# is there a way to reduce the number of (if function)Arduino push-button Code

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I finally made my push button on/off work,
the left button to turn on the LED and the right to turn off.
The LEDs are working in specific sequence, and I use `if` statement to do that but is there anyway to use less `if` statement in the code?

```
int start = 8;
int stop = 10;
bool status = false;
int Blue = 4;
int Yellow = 7;

int Delay = 1000;
long timeNow = 0;
long previoustime = 0;
int SY = LOW;
int SB = LOW;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(start,INPUT);
  pinMode(stop,INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  timeNow = millis();
 // Button
  if (digitalRead(start)==HIGH){
    status = true;
  }
  if(digitalRead(stop)== HIGH){
    status = false;
  }
  //Stop The LED
  if(status == false){
    SY=LOW;
    SB=LOW;
    
  }
    
  
  //start the LED
   if(status == true){
     if(timeNow - previoustime >= Delay){
       previoustime = timeNow;
       if(SY == LOW){
        SY = HIGH;      
       }else if (SY == HIGH && SB ==LOW){
            SY=LOW;
            SB=HIGH;
        }  else if (SB == HIGH && SY ==LOW){
            SY =HIGH;
         }  else{
                SB=LOW;
                SY = LOW;
          }
     }
   }
    digitalWrite(Yellow,SY);
    digitalWrite(Blue,SB);
}
```

[image]

I hope for a better way to write the code so I will learn more

Comment: Logic like `if (SY==LOW) {SY = HIGH;}` can be written as `SY = !SY;`.

Comment: You can toggle an LED state with something like `digitalWrite(LED_PIN, !digitalRead(LED_PIN));`. See [! operator](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/boolean-operators/logicalnot/).

Comment: @hcheung: `SY = ! SY;`  is completely different from `if (SY==LOW) SY = HIGH;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the status, its not necessary:

```
int start = 8;
int stop = 10;
int Blue = 4;
int Yellow = 7;

int Delay = 1000;
long timeNow = 0;
long previoustime = 0;
int SY = LOW;
int SB = LOW;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(start, INPUT);
    pinMode(stop, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    timeNow = millis();
    // Button
    if (digitalRead(start) == HIGH)
    {
        if (timeNow - previoustime >= Delay)
        {

            previoustime = timeNow;
            if (SY == LOW)
            {
                SY = HIGH;
            }
            else if (SY == HIGH && SB == LOW)
            {
                SY = LOW;
                SB = HIGH;
            }
            else if (SY == LOW && SB == HIGH)
            {
                SY = HIGH;
            }
            else
            {
                SB = LOW;
                SY = LOW;
            }
        }
    }
    if (digitalRead(stop) == HIGH)
    {
        SY = LOW;
        SB = LOW;
    }

    digitalWrite(Yellow, SY);
    digitalWrite(Blue, SB);
}
```